# Use Authorize Attribute with Custom Claims based Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization, claims-based-identity

I want to build my own authentication process using Claims based authentication in my ASP.net MVC project. I want to be able to use the Authorize attribute (including roles), for example `[Authorize(Roles="admin")]` and `[Authorize(Roles="Frontenduser")]` as I will have multiple types of users.

I don't want to use ASP.net identity as it does a bit too much than what I need. I also need totally different data to be stored for the different types of users.

I know I can inherit from the AuthorizeAttribute class but I am unsure how it all works with claims. So firstly, can anyone recommend a good package to use claims based authentication and secondly, how do I stop the Authorize attribute working with ASP.net Identity and get it to work with my custom claims based authentication?
I have had a look at other questions and other solutions across the web but I cannot find a suitable explanation or solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Policy based Authorization. Identity is Authentication and different than authorization. For this you can make a policy in your startup class. This is an example of mine in the configure services. If you dont need Identity you can use JWT bearer tokens and just make a policy.
get these packages from nuget:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;



      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

  //new policy makes [Authorize (Policy = "Your custom Policy")] availible by claims This is what you put on controllers
            services.AddAuthorization((options) => {
                options.AddPolicy("Your custom Policy", policybuilder =>
                {               
                    policybuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policybuilder.RequireClaim("role", "PayingUserExampleProperty");

                });
            });
```

in your configure

add

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
    app.UseAuthentication();
...
```

Good read into this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense and now I understand how to use claims and policies for authorisation, however I thought JWT bearer tokens are only used when accessing controllers through ajax / js. Alternatively, I will want to access the controllers directly using the url (links) and through mvc forms. For authentication, do you know how I can use my own system, for example if I have a class with a method that compares the user password to the db password, how would I tell the system and authorize attribute if the user is authenticated or unauthenticated? Does this make sense? Thanks

Comment: Yeah you need to understand that Authentication is not authorization. Authentication is who the user is and Identity is a awesome library that helps you make, and track users. Authorization is where that User can go in an app.There is no point in your app doing all that password query work , passwords are hashed using UserManager via Identity. These are all libraries and I know it sucks but just take your time and learn or write a custom version. You can do what you want by your user Inheriting from IdentityUser or you can add claims list and make roles for users and use Authorization policy